# psql: warning: extra command-line argument "postgres.dolphin.com" ignored

Tags: linux, postgresql, pg-dump

when I using this command to copy table `video` from database `dolphin` to database `acientbay` in Fedora 32, shows error like this:

```
/usr/share/postgresql-13/bin/pg_dump -v -t video -h postgres.dolphin.com -U postgres -p 5432 -d dolphin | /usr/share/postgresql-13/bin/psql -v -h postgres.dolphin.com -U postgres -p 5432 -d acientbay
```

where I am going wrong with my command? what should I do to fix it? The database was in the remote datacenter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In psql, the -v option takes an argument.  It does not mean verbose, like it does for pg_dump.  So the -v 'eats' the -h, considering an argument to -v.  That leaves postgres.dolphin.com as being just a bare argument not belonging to any option.  Normally that would be interpreted as the database name or as the user name, but since you already have `-d something` and `-U something`, that doesn't work.  So it doesn't what to do with this bare argument, and complains.